# pass dispatch function to another instance property as callback to execute later on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Sorry for pseudo-code. Think that the problem can be understood like so. Working in a reproducible example.

Consider the following pseudo code:

Class foo:

```
let fooInstance = null
class Foo() {
    constructor(){
        fooInstance = this;
        this.fooCallback = null // property to assign callback
    }

    static getInstance() {
        return fooInstance
    }

    callbackExecutor() {
        if (this.fooCallback)  // callback always null here even the assignment is ok in the component
            this.fooCallback();
    }
}
```

React-redux component:

```
import { argumentFunc } from 'src/argumentFunc'
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) { 
        ...
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const foo = Foo.getInstance()
        if (whateverCond) {
            // callback assignment to instance. this.props.argumentFunc() works if called here
            foo.fooCallback = this.props.argumentFunc(); 
        }
    }
}


...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    argumentFunc: () => dispatch(argumentFunc()),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

I assign the callback to the instance, but then in the `callbackExecutor`, `this.fooCallback` is null.

I tried:
`foo = this.props.argumentFunc();`
`foo = this.props.argumentFunc;`
`foo = () => this.props.argumentFunc();`
`foo = () => this.props.argumentFunc;`

How can I pass a callback to the instance (`fooInstance`) to be called later on within the class instance methods(`callbackExecutor()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
foo.getInstance().fooCallback = this.props.argumentFunc.bind(this)
```